# Menu Hierárquico NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou tentando montar um menu dinâmico com base nessa *table* aqui:

```
1   CONFIGURACOES   0       
2   ADMINISTRATIVO  0       
3   USUARIOS        2       
4   INSERIR_USUARIO 3       
5   ALTERAR_USUARIO 3       
6   EXCLUIR_USUARIO 3       
7   MENUS_DE_ACESSO 2       
8   DEPARTAMENTOS_DO_USUARIO    2
```

O menu deve apresentar o subMenu do menu correspondente de forma hierárquica, porém estou perdido aqui, tentei algumas coisas mas não montou do jeito que queria, alguém consegue me ajudar?

Estou usando a seguinte query para busca:

```
app.get('/listaMenus', function(req, res) {

    var conexao = app.servidor.mySQLConnect();


    listaMenus = function() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

            conexao.query("select * from MENU",
                function(err, rows) {
                    if (rows === undefined) {
                        reject(new Error('Linhas não forão populadas!'));
                    } else {
                        resolve(rows);
                    }
                }
            )
        })
    }
```

e na função estava tentando fazer uma adaptação de um código que encontrei em PHP.

```
function construirMenu(menus, menuFinal, menuSuperiorId, nivel = 0) {
            // Passando por todos os menus
            menus.forEach(dados => {
                // Se for um menu filho do menu superior que estamos procurando
                if (dados['ID_MENU_SUP'] == menuSuperiorId) {
                    // Armazenando no menu final
                    menuFinal.push(dados);
                }
                console.log(dados);
            });

            // Incrementando nível
            nivel++;
            // Passando pelos menus desse nível
            for (var i = 0; i < menuFinal.length; i++) {

                // Inicializando indices
                menuFinal[i].push('sub_menus') = [];
                menuFinal[i].push('nivel') = nivel;
                console.log(menuFinal);

                // Chamando a função novamente para construção dos submenus
                construirMenu(dados, menuFinal[i]['sub_menus'], '2', nivel);
            }

        }
        menuFinal = new Array();
        construirMenu(results, menuFinal, null);
        console.log(menuFinal);
```

estou tentando trazer mais o menos assim o resultado da API:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "menu_id_superior": null,
    "descricao": "Menu 1",
    "sub_menus": [
      {
        "id": "3",
        "menu_id_superior": "1",
        "descricao": "Menu 1.1",
        "sub_menus": [
          {
            "id": "4",
            "menu_id_superior": "3",
            "descricao": "Menu 1.1.1",
            "sub_menus": [
              {
                "id": "5",
                "menu_id_superior": "4",
                "descricao": "Menu 1.1.1.1",
                "sub_menus": [],
                "nivel": 4
              }
            ],
            "nivel": 3
          }
        ],
        "nivel": 2
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "menu_id_superior": "1",
        "descricao": "Menu 1.2",
        "sub_menus": [],
        "nivel": 2
      }
    ],
    "nivel": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "menu_id_superior": null,
    "descricao": "Menu 2",
    "sub_menus": [
      {
        "id": "7",
        "menu_id_superior": "2",
        "descricao": "Menu 2.1",
        "sub_menus": [],
        "nivel": 2
      },
      {
        "id": "8",
        "menu_id_superior": "2",
        "descricao": "Menu 2.2",
        "sub_menus": [],
        "nivel": 2
      }
    ],
    "nivel": 1
  }
]
```

porém com o meu menu

Contéudo das rows:

```
[ RowDataPacket {
    ID_MENU: 1,
    DESCRICAO: 'CONFIGURACOES',
    ID_MENU_SUP: 0,
    DT_CADASTRO: null,
    DT_ALTERACAO: null },
  RowDataPacket {
    ID_MENU: 2,
    DESCRICAO: 'ADMINISTRATIVO',
    ID_MENU_SUP: 0,
    DT_CADASTRO: null,
    DT_ALTERACAO: null },
  RowDataPacket {
    ID_MENU: 3,
    DESCRICAO: 'USUARIOS',
    ID_MENU_SUP: 2,
    DT_CADASTRO: null,
    DT_ALTERACAO: null },
  RowDataPacket {
    ID_MENU: 4,
    DESCRICAO: 'INSERIR_USUARIO',
    ID_MENU_SUP: 3,
    DT_CADASTRO: null,
    DT_ALTERACAO: null },
  RowDataPacket {
    ID_MENU: 5,
    DESCRICAO: 'ALTERAR_USUARIO',
    ID_MENU_SUP: 3,
    DT_CADASTRO: null,
    DT_ALTERACAO: null },
  RowDataPacket {
    ID_MENU: 6,
    DESCRICAO: 'EXCLUIR_USUARIO',
    ID_MENU_SUP: 3,
    DT_CADASTRO: null,
    DT_ALTERACAO: null },
  RowDataPacket {
    ID_MENU: 7,
    DESCRICAO: 'MENUS_DE_ACESSO',
    ID_MENU_SUP: 2,
    DT_CADASTRO: null,
    DT_ALTERACAO: null },
  RowDataPacket {
    ID_MENU: 8,
    DESCRICAO: 'DEPARTAMENTOS_DO_USUARIO',
    ID_MENU_SUP: 2,
    DT_CADASTRO: null,
    DT_ALTERACAO: null } ]
```

Comment: você poderia colocar mais informações na pergunta? Como qual a outra tabela com que essa esta se relacionado? Onde está a query que você está utilizando?

Comment: Adicione na pergunta o conteúdo da sua variável `rows`.

Comment: @roberto então mas aonde estão vindo as informações do SubMenus? E porque não poderia estar sendo feita a montagem vi query SQL?